# javascript : document.getElementById("xxx") won't works

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form below, which in the "select option" will trigger the function selectType(), I found that the function selectType() has been ran, because the alert works and show in the screen, then the "document.getElementById("selectType").submit();" seems won't works, because it wont go to the url I expected.

Edited at 2017/02/26 : Thanks for the answer.

I found that if the form inside "@using (Html.BeginForm())", then the "document.getElementById("selectType").submit();" won't works, if the form is outside the "@using (Html.BeginForm())", it works.

```
    <script>
        function selectType() {
            alert("aa");
            document.getElementById("selectType").submit();
        }
    </script>

    <form id="selectType" action="/TRecords/Audit">
        <input type="text" name="id" class="dateInput" value=@ViewBag.SId hidden>
        <select onchange="selectType();" name="auditType" class="form-control">
            <option>Select Type</option>
            <option value=1>A</option>
            <option value=2>B</option>
            <option value=3>C</option>
            <option value=4>D</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: `name` is not `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "document.getElementById("selectType").submit();" seems won't works

Because you have set `name` of form to be `selectType` and not `id`.

1. Either set `<form id="selectType">..</form>`
2. Or if name is must, then use `document.getElementsByName('selectType')[0].submit();`

Answer (score 1):

Just change 'name' to 'id'.

```
<form id="selectType" action="/TRecords/Audit">
```

In order to use 'getElementById' method your need to access using 'id' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right but this line:

`<form name="selectType" action="/TRecords/Audit">`.

Need to be change for that:

`<form id="selectType" action="/TRecords/Audit">`

Comment: Please try and provide guidance on why the line needs to be changed so that @kaihong can better understand their mistake. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

I found that if the form inside `@using (Html.BeginForm())` then the `document.getElementById("selectType").submit();` won't work. If the form is outside `@using (Html.BeginForm())` it works.